# Violation Primary Key, tries to insert foreign key table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I try to add new record to Rules table. While inserting rule table, I getting an error like it tries to insert to its relational table. I do similar insertion things before, but I have never got this error. I also searched and tried other users' suggestion but not worked for me.

```
 public class RuleDomainModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]//tried
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //[Key] //tried
    public int? BranchID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BranchID")]//tried
    public virtual BranchDomainModel Branch { get; set; }
}

public class BranchDomainModel : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]//tried
    [Key]
    public int ObjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UnitDomainModel> Units { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BranchID")]//tried
    public virtual ICollection<RuleDomainModel> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings like;

```
public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<RuleDomainModel>().ToTable("Rules");
        builder.Entity<RuleDomainModel>().HasKey(t => t.ObjectID);
        builder.Entity<RuleDomainModel>().Property(t =>t.Name);
        builder.Entity<RuleDomainModel>().HasOne(t => t.Branch).WithMany(t => t.Rules).HasForeignKey(t => t.BranchID).HasPrincipalKey(t => t.ObjectID);
    }

 public void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<BranchDomainModel>().ToTable("Branch");
        builder.Entity<BranchDomainModel>().HasKey(t => t.ObjectID);
        builder.Entity<BranchDomainModel>().Property(t => t.Name);
        builder.Entity<BranchDomainModel>().HasMany(m => m.Units).WithOne(x => x.Branch).HasForeignKey(x => x.xxxID).HasPrincipalKey(m => m.ObjectID);
    }
```

And this is the point that throws exception:

```
if (model.ObjectID == 0)
{
    RuleDomainModel mod = Mapper.Map<RuleDomainModel>(model);
    uow.Repository<RuleDomainModel>().Add(mod);
    uow.Commit(requestOwnerModel); // Cannot insert duplicate key error
}
else
 {
    var mod = Mapper.Map<RuleDomainModel>(model);
    uow.Repository<RuleDomainModel>().Update(mod);
    uow.Commit(requestOwnerModel);
 }
```

I hope somebody helps, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding `model.Branch = null` after mapping to domain model. But I don't know this is the best way. If anybody knows please write here. Thanks.

Comment: Attach `model.Branch` to the context before adding `model`.